# How to make div expandible with floated content

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

I want to design an expandible `div`, which should expand as per the content inside. The content has two `div`s, floated left, each having a fixed width. These `div`s are themselves expandible as per their text content. Finally their is a `div` in the parent `div` following these `div`s meant two clear the two floats. However the parent `div` doesn't expand to contain the child `div`s, though I think it should, because all the elements are relatively positioned, not absolutely positioned. How can I achieve the expansion? The fiddle is at http://jsfiddle.net/Cupidvogel/y79NS/1/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add float:left to your main div ".main" (and doing so you won't need the clear:both div anymore as all the elements are floated now)

http://jsfiddle.net/y79NS/4/

You can still use the clear:both property like you have in your example, and this way you don't need to add float:left to the main div, but you have the clear div in the wrong place. This should be placed inside the float right div, alternativly you can remove the .clear div and use ":after" to clear the divs:

http://jsfiddle.net/y79NS/5/

and here's a [link](http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html/) that will explain why this works.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you could try adding `overflow: hidden;` to `.main` class style.

Comment: It gives your main div a "wake up call" to look inside its contents (if anything is overflowing) and tries to show as much as possible and hiding the rest. If there is space available it shows inner divs and other content nicely. This is pretty weird how it acts but it works usually.